# て used as "because"?

Tags: grammar, translation, て-form, conjunctions

My (Japanese) friend gave me a suggested translation of this sentence:

> 普段ワインはなかなか飲まないのだけど、いろんな味、風味、渋味甘味が感じられて良き体験でした。
>
> By no means do I usually drink wine but, it was a good experience *because* I drank various flavours, sweet/bitter flavours.

He told me he thought て was acting as なので. Is this the case?

Comment: In its current form it's a proofreading question and nothing more.

Comment: It is correct that the て-from can be used to give a reason. If you want to know more you need a more specific question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, te-form can often denote a reason or a cause, but it's not as explicit as ～なので or *because* in English. Most of the time, "AてB" is more naturally translated as "A, and B", "A, so B" rather than "Because A, B".

See this article: [te-form (て-form) for Cause or Reason](http://www.learn-japanese-adventure.com/te-form-cause-reason.html)