# use of the に in 一番に, and about て form

Tags: particle-に, て-form

Hi can someone help me to figure out what that に in 朝起きて一番に is doing? I´m confused. is it indicating an absolute time, or is it making it an adverbial for what comes next? and also, all the て forms is the connective -and-?

> 朝起きて一番に中庭に集まって家族みんなで太極拳をします

Comment: [一番に](https://thesaurus.weblio.jp/content/%E4%B8%80%E7%95%AA%E3%81%AB) is just another way of saying 最初に.

Comment: [This](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/61372/differentiate-a-cause-from-a-succession-of-terms-in-a-sentence-using-%ef%bd%9e%e3%81%8f%e3%81%a6-%e3%81%a7/61377#61377) may help clarify things in regards to the て form usage and its relation to and

Comment: so 一番に   is an adverbial like 最初に?

Comment: btw thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This 一番に is an adverb that means "first(ly)". に is a particle that makes the **previous** word adverbial. For example 永遠 means "eternity" and 永遠に means "eternally". 元気 means "energy/spirit" and 元気に means "energetically". Likewise, 一番 means "number one" or "the first/top", and 一番に is its adverbial version.

Those te-forms are just connecting several actions, namely 起きる, 集まる, and (太極拳を)する.

- 彼は一番に到着した。
  He arrived first. / He was the first to arrive.
- 朝起きて一番に中庭に集まって家族みんなで太極拳をします。
  The first thing my family do in the morning is gather in the courtyard and do tai chi together.